# Qt Creator - How to run program with cmd line arguments involving process substitution

Tags: bash, shell, qt-creator

I am trying to run my program from Qt Creator with command line options involving process substitution. Here's the command (I want each line written to file to be prepended with the time and date, achieved by predate.sh, while the output to the terminal remains unchanged):

```
$ exec | tee >(predate.sh > output.txt)
```

However, I get the error

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

My default shell is bash and the SHELL variable in my run environment is also /bin/bash. This command works if I execute the program from the terminal but not when launched in Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process substitution is a feature of `bash`, whereas QtCreator is apparently hardcoded to use `sh` to execute the run command. You can inject `bash` into your command as follows:

```
$ exec | bash -c 'tee >(predate.sh > output.txt)'
```

Comment: excellent, works perfectly! Predating the output to both terminal and file was causing some weirdness with the line endings on the terminal, that's avoided now. Thanks